# concatenation of contexts

Tags: type-theory

I'm reading [an nlab article about type theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Martin-L%C3%B6f+dependent+type+theory). It is written that

> If $\Gamma\vdash A:\mathrm{Type}$ and $\Delta\vdash B:\mathrm{Type}$, then $\Gamma, \Delta\vdash A\times B:\mathrm{Type}$

What is $\Gamma, \Delta$ on the left side of $\Gamma, \Delta \vdash A\times B:\mathrm{Type}$?

If $\Gamma$ is $x:T$ and $\Delta$ is $y:U$, I think $\Gamma, \Delta$ is $x:T, y:U$. However,

1. What if $\Gamma=x:T$ and $\Delta=x:T$? Is it $x:T, x:T$ or $x:T$?
2. What if $\Gamma=x:T$ and $\Delta=x:U$? ($T\neq U$)

Comment: I do not know why this is closed. This is a question of type theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collision on variable names has to be solved by variable renaming. This is however usually done implicitely: collisions, and renaming are mentioned only when really needed, or when they can be source of confusion.

So in $\Gamma, \Delta \vdash$, we implicitely suppose that the variables of $\Delta$ have been renamed to prevent collision (note that $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ define a *list* of variables, not always a single variable $x$).
The new names are not specified, any choice is Ok, provided there is no collision.
With your examples a solution could be $x:T,y:T$ in the 1st case, $x:T,y:U$ in the 2nd case.